# Does "std::string + char" expression create another std::string?

Tags: c++, performance, memory

Does the expression below create another std::string and then add it to s1?

```
    std::string s1 = "abc", s2 = "xyz";
    s1 += s2 + 'b';
```

Should it prevent this situation (they'd be added to s1 without additional work)?

```
    std::string s1 = "abc", s2 = "xyz";
    s1 += s2;
    s1 += 'b';
```

Do these rules apply to "std::string + std::string" expressions as well?

Comment: Your question title doesn't match the question details.

Comment: These are equally fast. No difference.

Comment: The "fix" for what? What is the problem? Also, stack/heap are misleading/wrong/irrelevant here, particularly since `std::string` dynamically allocates its buffer.

Comment: `s1 = s2 + 'b';` and `s1 += s2; s1 += 'b';` generally don't do the same thing. They only end up having the same effect if initially, `s1` is empty, but if `s1` is known to be empty, writing `s1 += s2;` rather than `s1 = s2;` makes no sense.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit "`std::string` dynamically allocates its buffer" is misleading because it may use small string optimization.

Comment: I'm guessing the first snippet should create a temporary on the stack (if not optimized away). After the edit this is a reasonable question. I'm not sure why it was downvoted.

Comment: Print some addresses and see what happens.

Comment: @Muscampester: It was downvoted before the edit, obviously.

Comment: @LightTab No, your edit is not in accordance with the answer. The answer needs editing.

Comment: @tuple_cat: Touché!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All overloaded `+` operators involving a `std::string` return a new `std::string` object. This is the inescapable conclusion you will reach when [you finally decipher the relevant documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B).

As such, in the first example in your question, the `+` operator will return a temporary object, which will get destroyed upon completion of the immediately-following `+=` operation.

Having said that: a C++ compiler is permitted to employ any optimization that produces identical observable results. It is remotely possible that a C++ compiler might figure out that it is possible to avoid the need to create a temporary object by transforming the first version of the code to the second one, essentially. I don't think that's very likely, but it's possible. There are no observable differences in the results between the two versions of the code, so that optimization is fair game.

But, technically, the `+` operation produces a temporary `std::string` object.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on context. In your code snippet there won't be another object, `s2` and `'b'` will be appended to already existing `s1`.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator+=/

For example in this case:

```
std::string s1 = "abc";
std::string s2 = "zxy";
std::string result = s1 + s2;
```

`result` is new object concatenating `s1` and `s2`

Comment: Are you sure? `s2 + 'b'` looks like a distinct, temporary `std::string` to me. The real answer is "who cares" because at worst that temporary will be moved into `s1`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: yes it'll create a temporary object which the constructor takes a single character

Comment: That syntax is "copy-initialization", so `result` is a (C++03: copy, C++11 and later: move) of a new temporary object concatenating `s1` and `s2`.

Comment: @Raindrop7: That's not the reason.  There's an overload of `operator+` which takes a string and a single character, the single character is not implicitly converted to a string.  The extra temporary everyone is talking about is the return value from `operator+`.

Comment: @BenVoigt: "*C++03: copy, C++11 and later: move*" And in C++17, neither. Thanks to guaranteed elision, the result is created directly in `result`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit in std::string += operator documentation it's clearly written that will append, for + operator it's written that it will return new objects. All your posts are optimisation that compiler might or might not use. Please refer to documentation: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator+/ http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator+=/

Comment: @paweldac: Huh? No.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit from += operator: Append to string
Extends the string by appending additional characters at the end of its current value:

(See member function append for additional appending options).

Comment: @Nicol: I just reread the section on copy-initialization, and the section on copy/move elision, from draft n4618, and I don't see that guarantee.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit from + operator: Concatenate strings
Returns a newly constructed string object with its value being the concatenation of the characters in lhs followed by those of rhs.

Comment: _"Returns a newly constructed string object"_ Yes, that's what I said, and the opposite of what your answer says.

Comment: @paweldac: Yes, and then the language rules, since C++11, require using a move (not copy) constructor to get the value of that temporary into `result`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit it won't change what? That compier might do some optimisations, that are not required by standard?

Comment: @BenVoigt: That's because it's "hidden". See, `operator+` returns a prvalue. Pre-C++17, that would mean it returns a temporary. But C++17's guaranteed elision rules mean that it *doesn't* return a temporary; it returns a, for want of a better term, "thing", which can initialize an object. That thing can *manifest* a temporary, but such manifestation will *only* happen if the prvalue is used to initialize something that isn't its own type. Temporaries only appear based on how prvalues get used.

Comment: @BenVoigt can you give standard section that requires compiler to use move constructor or copy/move-elision optimisation?

Comment: @paweldac: I am not talking about any "optimisations". I am saying what the semantics of the code snippet are guaranteed to be. The wording you quoted from cplusplus.com backs up those claims. The only way that your answer is correct is if the copy/move were guaranteed to be elided; that may become true in C++17, but C++17 is not a language that currently exists.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Ahh, so the change is in "Basic concepts: Lvalues and rvalues".  That does look different, I'll have to study it further.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit can you provide section in standard that you're referring to?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Which part of the standard do you want me to cite? And why, when you just copy/pasted those exact rules from cplusplus.com for me to read, saying "please refer to documentation"? I'm really confused about what we're discussing now. Perhaps it would be best to put this to bed.

Comment: @paweldac: prvalue expressions preferentially bind to rvalue reference parameters. `std::string` has an `operator=` overload that takes an rvalue reference to a string. Therefore, using that operator on a prvalue temporary (pre-C++17) will provoke a move. That's move-assignment 101.

Comment: @paweldac: Section `[over.ics.rank]` "Standard conversion sequence `S1` is a better conversion sequence than standard conversion sequence `S2`
if... `S1` and `S2` are reference bindings and neither refers to an implicit object parameter of a non-static member function declared without a ref-qualiﬁer, and `S1` binds an rvalue reference to
an rvalue and `S2` binds an lvalue reference."  This rule forces the compiler to choose the move constructor in preference over the copy constructor, because `std::string` has both.